# Why should I use sstore method in solidity?

Tags: contract-development

**assembly**
What is the difference between using storage and this method?

```
assembly {
    //allows you to store a value in storage
      sstore(slot, _admin)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Solc will compile storage access to bytecode using the `sstore` opcode.

I recommend to avoid assembly if possible. The compiler does a good job avoiding some problems by adding checks where possible.